# Several CSS3 Keyframes not working/have wrong positions in Firefox 19

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

I have some trouble with Firefox und CSS3 Keyframes. With Chrome and Safari there are no problems. It seems as though FF ignore the CSS command 'top', but I do not know why. 
I change the position to relative, but no success.

The Code:

```
.tile {
     position:absolute;
     z-index:10;
     background-color:#e20074;
     width:5px;
     height:5px;
 }     

#tile1 {
 animation:tile1 6s linear infinite;
 /* older Firefox: */
 -moz-animation:tile1 6s linear infinite;
 /* Safari and Chrome: */
 -webkit-animation:tile1 6s linear infinite;
 /* Opera: */
 -o-animation:tile1 6s linear infinite; 
}

@keyframes tile1 {
 0%      { left:10px; visibility:visible;}
 10%     { left:20px; top:10px; }
 20%     { left:30px; top:15px; }
 30%     { left:40px; top:10px; }
 40%     { left:50px; top:0px; }
 50%     { left:60px; top:10px; }
 60%     { left:70px; top:15px; }
 70%     { left:80px; top:10px; }
 80%     { left:90px; top:0px; }
 90%     { left:100px; top:10px; }
 100%    { left:115px; top:15px; }
}
```

I have made a small text box that does practically the same and it works. I can't figure it out what is wrong in the Code above.

```
#testbox {
    position:relative;
    background-color:Blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    animation: test 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes test {
    0% { left:100px; top:100px; }
    100% { left:10px; top:10px; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is searching for `top` position to start.

You may want to look for an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/Hq4qk/1/)

Comment: Oh jesus! I knew it is a very small overseeable error. Thank you so much, bro! :-)